# I still can access page after restarting Spring Boot Application and create-drop H2 database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, h2

I still can access page after restart Spring boot app with H2 database, in my application.properties I set create-drop, I do not see snippets, but I can access /code/latest and see username before restarting. In /h2-console there are no users and snippets.

```
server.port=8889
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/static/**
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./mydb;
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.settings.trace=false
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=false
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers(
                                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login/**"),
                                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/register"),
                                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/static/**")
                        )
                                .permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers(toH2Console()).permitAll()

                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/code/latest", true))
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(toH2Console()).disable())
                .headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/code")
public class PlatformWebController {
    private final PlatformService platformService;
    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public PlatformWebController(PlatformService platformService, UserService userService) {
        this.platformService = platformService;
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/{id}", produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    public String getCode(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("codeEntity", platformService.getCode(id));
        return "snippet";
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/new", produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    public String getForm() {
        return "form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/new")
    public String addSnippet(@RequestBody Snippet snippet, @AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails) {
        log.info("Username: " + userDetails.getUsername());
        User user = userService.getUserByUsername(userDetails.getUsername());

        if(user == null) {
            return "/security/login";
        }
        snippet.setAuthor(user);
        snippet.setDate(LocalDateTime.now());
        platformService.addSnippet(snippet);
        return "redirect:/code/latest";
    }

    @GetMapping("/latest")
    public String getLatest(Model model, @AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails) {
        log.info("User is authenticated: " + userDetails.getUsername());
        log.info(platformService.getLatest().toString());
        model.addAttribute("username", userDetails.getUsername());
        model.addAttribute("latest", platformService.getLatest());
        return "latest";
    }
}
```

After restart I see this in my spring boot console:

2023-09-11T16:34:22.968+02:00  INFO 22276 --- [nio-8889-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2023-09-11T16:34:22.973+02:00 DEBUG 22276 --- [nio-8889-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /code/latest
2023-09-11T16:34:22.977+02:00 DEBUG 22276 --- [nio-8889-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=a, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ADMIN]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=3688B6240E7E1C137DD8FDCF539CEDF9], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ADMIN]]]
2023-09-11T16:34:22.978+02:00 DEBUG 22276 --- [nio-8889-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /code/latest
2023-09-11T16:34:22.992+02:00  INFO 22276 --- [nio-8889-exec-1] c.v.p.controller.PlatformWebController   : User is authenticated: a
2023-09-11T16:34:23.059+02:00  INFO 22276 --- [nio-8889-exec-1] c.v.p.controller.PlatformWebController   : []
2023-09-11T16:34:23.267+02:00 DEBUG 22276 --- [nio-8889-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /static/css/style.css
2023-09-11T16:34:23.268+02:00 DEBUG 22276 --- [nio-8889-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /static/css/style.css
2023-09-11T16:34:23.270+02:00 DEBUG 22276 --- [nio-8889-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /static/js/script.js
2023-09-11T16:34:23.270+02:00 DEBUG 22276 --- [nio-8889-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /static/js/script.js
2023-09-11T16:34:23.279+02:00 DEBUG 22276 --- [nio-8889-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=a, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ADMIN]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=3688B6240E7E1C137DD8FDCF539CEDF9], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ADMIN]]]
2023-09-11T16:34:23.280+02:00 DEBUG 22276 --- [nio-8889-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=a, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ADMIN]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=3688B6240E7E1C137DD8FDCF539CEDF9], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ADMIN]]]

I tried to change SecurityConfig and set sessionCreationPolicy but after that I cannot to log in after registration.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.